# Get session from cordova webview

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova, session

In my cordova app i am loading a web application. In my app the login details are stored in session. When closing the app and re open it shows as logged in. I want to retrieve the stored sessions. My cordova code is shown below.

**index.js**

```
var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {
    window.location.replace("http://xxx.xxx.xxx:30/");
    this.bindEvents();
    },
    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        app.receivedEvent('deviceready');   
    },
    receivedEvent: function(id) {
        var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
        var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
        var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');
        console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
    }
};
app.initialize();
```

In my web app `$.session.set("username", $resData.username);` is used for storing session. but when i am using `$.session.get("username")` in index.js. I didn't get value. How to retrieve the sesion values.

Comment: if session is not working you can use localstorage.setItem and  localstorage.getItem for achieving this

Comment: The session storing code is wriiten in web app page.

Comment: you will have to check how the `"http://xxx.xxx.xxx:30/` stores session. Probably it uses cookies, or whatever. You need to know that first

Comment: It uses session. The jquery code is $.session.set("username", $resData.username);